# mkdir based on input from other directories

Tags: shell, directory, file-copy

I have a directory full of albums I've ripped to FLAC format. Folders are named "Artist - Album [flac]" I need to create matching directories named "Artist - Album [mp3]" but only for certain folders...

So "ls | grep Pantera" gives me the list of directories I want to work with...

How can do I do this via command line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use xargs to use the output of one command as arguments to run another; but but using the output of `ls` for this is crazy problematic because of spaces and quoting issues. In order to accomplish what you are suggesting if there are any spaces in the names produced you would have to do something like this:

```
ls | grep Pantera | sed -e 's/\[flac\]/[mp3]/' | xargs -n1 -i{} mkdir "{}"
```

However the a **much better** tool for this would be to use the `find` command and `-exec` option. Unless someone knows how to make use of bash's string functions on a literal string instead of a variable or set and use a variable in one command, you will need [ssapkota's syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/mkdir-based-on-input-from-other-directories/14921#14921) to launch a subshell.

When using find, also consider options such as `-type d` to only return directory matches (or `-type f` for files). You could remove the `-maxdepth 1` if you wanted to do a recursive find. It's also possible the pattern matching could be refined for your scenario.

Comment: I also agree in utilizing `find`, but the command line provided is incomplete. It does not create a _[mp3]_ from a _[flac]_ dir.

Comment: You're quite right. I'll fix this to answer the whole problem not just the output as arguments problem.

Comment: The second answer you gave isn't working. It throws a `find: missing argument to -exec`

Comment: Hmmm ... might need to escape those `&`'s ... or drop them. Hang on I'll figure it out.

Comment: @Caleb: You need to invoke a shell as the `-exec` command. [ssapkota's answer shows how](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14915/mkdir-based-on-input-from-other-directories/14921#14921).

Comment: @Gilles @ssapkota I figured out that would work but decided it was too ugyl, so I was over here trying to figure out how to make use of bash string replacement on one line. Bash does fine with a var but can't seem to use any of it's string operators on literal strings. :(

Answer (score 2):

Find is the best tool for it. But `find` just allows a single command and doesn't support chaining.

Here's the solution that works by forking a subshell for each matched directory name.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -iname "*Pantera*" -exec  \
    bash -c ' name="{}" && mkdir "${name/flac/mp3}" ' \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are all the files in the same directory? Then you can use a simple loop plus shell string manipulation constructs.

```
for flac_dir in *Pantera*'[flac]'/; do
  flac_dir=${flac_dir%/}
  mp3_dir="${x%\[flac\]}[mp3]"
  mkdir "$mp3_dir"
done
```

If you want to act recursively in subdirectories as well, under zsh, or under bash ≥4, you can use `for flac_dir in **/*Pantera*'[flac]'/`. With bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first.